# Superscript affects line height

Tags: android, textview

When I display a text in `TextView` containing a superscript, I noticed that the line height of the line where the superscript is written is larger. The line height difference is very noticeable.

How do I make the line height of all the lines the same regardless if I have a superscript or subscript? Or is there a way to set the superscript not to consume too much line height?

My code for my superscript is: `<sup>123</sup>`. Then I am using `Html.fromHtml` to make sure that it will be rendered using the Html tags.

I've also tried using: `<sup><small>123</small></sup>`. But it only made the text smaller and the text did not become a superscript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, the `<small>` tag works. I'm not sure why it didn't work on my first try but it must be because I have to clean Eclipse first. Anyways, to make the effect more visible, using the `<small>` tag twice will do. As such it will be:

```
<small><small>superscript</small></small>
```

Answer (score 1):

use unicode for that link "\u2122"

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2122/index.htm

so find same for 1 ,2 ,3

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00b9/index.htm

Unicode Character 'SUPERSCRIPT ONE' : \u00B9

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm?q=2&preview=entity

Comment: The trademark sign works but the superscript sign for the numbers is not recognized by the phone. The unicode for the superscript of 0 is \u2070. But it is only displayed as a rectangular box on my phone. I guess Android does not support some of the unicode characters. Is there any other way?

Comment: I tried the other numbers and it seems the other numbers are working. Also, I need to use superscript a comma? Is there a unicode for the superscript of comma?

Comment: there are various types of commas but not looks fine for this condition http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm?q=%2C&preview=entity

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I tried using the single quote , however, it is still very obvious that it is not a comma. The single quote is displayed at the same level of the superscript and since its height is shorter than the superscript, it still looks like a single quote. On the other hand, the types of commas is not recognized by Android by default. It is only displayed as a rectangle on my phone.